# Node.js - strange TypeError when function being called twice within class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, asynchronous, typeerror

Consider this (simplified) extract from a class:

```
function PluginsEngine() {
    this.allPluggins = require('./plugins');
};

PluginsEngine.prototype.applyPlugins = function(incomingData, done){

    // bind the incoming data to each plugin
    var key;
    for (key in this.allPluggins)
        this.allPluggins[key] = this.allPluggins[key].bind(undefined, incomingData);

    async.parallel(this.allPluggins, done);
};
```

The constructor loads a set of anonymous functions and the "applyPlugins" method then passes the "incomingData" (string) to each and these are executed using async.

When writing tests against this I am seeing a strange behavior in that calling "applyPlugins" runs fine, but calling it again immediately afterwards causes the error:

```
TypeError: string is not a function
```

Adding some additional debug, I can see that allPluggins is empty (functions not available) when run the second time.

Can anyone advise why the variable is losing the functions?

Comment: Is `this.allPluggins[key].bind()` returning a string?

Comment: Hi @Michael - Thanks for the input. I can confirm no, always a function as expected.